# How to upload multiple images from Reactjs using C# WebAPI .Net core 5.0

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-hooks

I am new to Reactjs and learning it, I am trying to upload multiple images from Reactjs component and used the C# Web API in the backend, but each time I am getting the Request.Form.Files count =0 in the WEB API action method, I am able to upload the sing;e image but now trying with multiple and facing the issue,  Below is the component code:

```js
import Header from './Header'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function Add() {

    const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
    const [productCode, setProductCode] = useState("");
    const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState("");
    const [productDescription, setProductDescription] = useState("");
    const [productImage, setProductImage] = useState([]);

    // useEffect(()=>{

    //     AddProduct();

        
    // },[] )

    async function AddProduct() {

       // let data={productName, productCode, productPrice, productDescription}

        const formData = new FormData();
        for(let i=0;i<productImage.length;i++){
            // console.log(productImage)
            formData.append("productImage"+i, productImage);
       }
        // formData.append("productImage", productImage);
        formData.append("productName", productName);
        formData.append("productCode", productCode);
        formData.append("productPrice", productPrice);
        formData.append("productDescription", productDescription);
        formData.append("userName",localStorage.getItem("UserName"));

        console.warn("Sonu ", formData)
        console.log(productImage)

        let result = await fetch("https://localhost:44353/ApiProduct/AddProduct", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {},
            body: formData,
        })
        let response=await result.json();
        if(response.status)
        {
            alert (response.successMessage)
        }
        else{
            alert (response.errorMessage)

        }

    }
    function onImageChange(e) {
        setProductImage([...e.target.files]);
      }
        return (

            <div>
                <Header />
                <h1>Add Product</h1>
                <div className='col-6 offset-3' >
                    <input type="text" placeholder='productName'  className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)} /><br /><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder='productCode'  className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setProductCode(e.target.value)} /><br /><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder='productPrice'  className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setProductPrice(e.target.value)} /><br /><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder='productDescription'  className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setProductDescription(e.target.value)} /><br /><br />
                    <input type="file"  multiple accept=".jpg"  className='form-control' onChange={(e) => onImageChange(e)} /><br /><br />
                    

                    <Button onClick={AddProduct}>Add Products</Button>
                </div>
            </div>


        );
    }

    export default Add;
```

Below is the API Code..

```js
 public ResponseData AddProduct([FromForm] IList<IFormFile> files)
                        {
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            if(files?.Any())
            {
            // Each time in my case files count is showing zero.
            }
            else
            {
            // other Logic
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have used the C# Web API in the backend, but each time I am getting
> the Request.Form.Files count =0 in the WEB API action method, I am
> able to upload the sing;e image but now trying with multiple and
> facing the issue.

Well, to begin with your issue, while you wowuld send request to API controller you ought to match parameter name same as your controller with your `fromData` submit parameter. In your case, your controller parameter name is `files` however, you are binding your `formData` paramter as `formData.append("productImage"+i, productImage);` which is incorreect that's causing data-loss at submission.

In addition, not sure what did you mean by `public ResponseData AddProduct` API controller name. Furthermore, here is the complete sample how you could send list of image from your react request to Asp.net core API controller.

From Data Binding in React:

```
async function AddProduct(productImage) {

            const formData = new FormData();
            if (productImage.length > 0) {
             
                for (let i = 0; i < productImage.length; i++) {
                     let image = productImage[i];
                    formData.append('files', image);
                }
               
            }

            let result = await fetch("https://localhost:44353/ApiProduct/AddProduct", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {},
                body: form,
            });
            console.log(result.status);

        }
```

**Note:** Be confirmed about `AddProduct(productImage)` here, `productImage` is each image I am passing while choosing image, you need to pass the parameter here. In addition, here `form.append('files', files);` files is your controller parametere must match accordingly.

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            return Ok(files);
        }
```

Output:

[image]